# confused about printing from tuples

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I'm having trouble figuring out some printing in python. Here is my code:

I have created boat tuple with name crew size, number of rowers, and coxswain or no coxswain. I am trying to get the types of boats I can use in lineups given how many rowers I have and how many coxswains i have through avboats(). The function filters as desired, but for some reason does not print.

```
#boat tuples
Single = ("1x", 1, 1, False)
Pair = ("2-", 2, 2, False)
Double = ("2x", 2, 2, False)
Quad = ("4x", 4, 4, False)
StraightFour = ("4-", 4, 4, False)
CoxedPair = ("2+", 2, 3, True)
CoxedFour = ("4+", 4, 5, True)
Eight = ("8+", 8, 9, True)

allboats = {Single, Pair, Double, Quad, StraightFour, CoxedFour, CoxedPair, Eight}
coxedboats = {CoxedPair, CoxedFour, Eight}
blindboats = {Single, Double, Quad, Pair}

def avboats(numofrowers, numofcox):
    # Initialize the list of possible boats
    possboats = allboats.copy()  
    
    # Check if the number of cox is greater than 0
    if numofcox > 0:
        # Remove boats with more rowers than available
        possboats = [boat for boat in possboats if numofrowers >= boat[1]]
        return possboats
    
    # If the number of cox is 0 or less, remove boats with a cox
    else:
        possboats = [boat for boat in possboats if not boat[3]]
        return possboats
    available_boats = avboats(numofrowers, numofcox)
    print("Available boats for", num_rowers, "rowers and", num_coxswains, "coxswain(s) are:")
    for boat in available_boats:
        print(boat[0])
```

When i call the function it returns something like:

```
>>>avboats(5,2)
[('2-', 2, 2, False), ('4+', 4, 5, True), ('2x', 2, 2, False), ('4-', 4, 4, False), ('4x', 4, 4, False), ('1x', 1, 1, False), ('2+', 2, 3, True)]
```

Instead of what i'm expecting to be: 2-, 4+, 2, etc.

I've asked chat GPT and tried a few different things myself, like making the tuples into dictionaries instead. This threw a hashing error. I don't know why it isn't just printing the boat names. When I run:

```
num_rowers = 8
num_coxswains = 1
available_boats = avboats(num_rowers, num_coxswains)
print("Available boats for", num_rowers, "rowers and", num_coxswains, "coxswain(s) are:")
for boat in available_boats:
    print(boat[0])
it prints what I want:
Available boats for 8 rowers and 1 coxswain(s) are:
2+
2x
4x
4-
2-
4+
8+
1x
```

Comment: You're returning the whole boat tuples. You'd need to do something like you're doing in that `for` loop at the end, like `print(board[0] for boat in avboats(5,2)]`, or do that projection in the function itself.

Comment: Why doesn't having ` for boat in possboats: print(boat[0])` yield the desired result? I'm putting it at the end of the function

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want. Explanation is given as and where it is required.

```
all_boats  =   {
        'Single' : ["1x", 1, 1, False],
        'Pair' : ["2-", 2, 2, False],
        'Double' : ["2x", 2, 2, False],
        'Quad' : ["4x", 4, 4, False],
        'StraightFour' : ["4-", 4, 4, False],
        'CoxedPair' : ["2+", 2, 3, True],
        'CoxedFour' : ["4+", 4, 5, True],
        'Eight' : ["8+", 8, 9, True]
        }

def avboats(numofrowers, numofcox):

    if numofcox > 0:
    
        #iterate thru values of the dict and return value should be boat[0]
        passboats = [boat[0] for boat in all_boats.values() if numofrowers >= boat[1]]
    
    else:
        
        #iterate thru values of the dict and return value should be boat[0]
        passboats = [boat[0] for boat in all_boats.values() if not boat[3]]
    
    return passboats

r = avboats(5,2)
print(r) #Output: ['1x', '2-', '2x', '4x', '4-', '2+', '4+']
```